# How to avoid reflections/shadows while shooting real framed/glass picture?

Tags: outdoor, shadows, lightning

I'm supposed to make a few shots of someone's printed pictures. They are in glass frames. But, until uploading to my computer, I didn't realize none of the photos are good because there are reflections of the objects around. It was supposed to be a creative shoot, so somewhere the printed picture is laying on the ground, and all the trees and buildings are reflecting on it...

Is there any tricks i can do to avoid this while reshooting tomorrow?

Note that I still haven't tried anything. I thought I could put a textile cloth or something above or something like that ... not sure if it makes sense ... So, please help asap!

Comment: Related: [How to avoid reflection when taking a picture of a ceramic object with a shiny glaze?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/3602)

Comment: Related: [How do I eliminate reflection on glass?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/21766)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to photograph glass without reflections and shadows?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/20839/how-to-photograph-glass-without-reflections-and-shadows)

Comment: Duplicate: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6625/how-do-you-photograph-artwork-in-a-glass-picture-frame/79902#79902

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you photograph artwork in a glass picture frame?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6625/how-do-you-photograph-artwork-in-a-glass-picture-frame)

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions:

It seems simplistic, but would a polarizing filter work ?
It's good for reflection on windows or water, why not a frame ? Remember to tune it right by turning it.

Another aspect is focus. You must be sure that your AF is not focusing on the reflection (a reflected object "counts" as more distant, thus not focusing at the same plane as the frame). Maybe you should consider using manual focus and choosing the frame as you subject. In that case, the reflection might be there, but out of focus (and prettier).

Comment: Hello! Thanks a lot for the answer! I need to figure out something quickly, so I ended up photoshopping the digital photo of the picture as a new layer, fixing the shadows and reflections that way.

Thank you for quick answer anyway!

Best,

Jovan